# Plot elements of specific size

Tags: matlab-figure

I'm plotting a polygon made of edges and vertices. I'd like to plot these elements at a specific size or proportion: whether the polygon has 10 or 1000 vertices, I'd like the elements to be drawn at the same size. When zooming in and out of the vector image, element size would remain static.
For example, define a canvas of 100inx100in and draw lines .1in thick (and save to a pdf).

Currently, it seems impossible since, e.g., the `LineWidth`, `MarkerSize`, and `FontSize` are relative to the screen instead of the canvas. This means that when you zoom into the figure, the elements keep their size wrt screen. One option is to scale their size according to the zoom level. However, then the large polygon wouldn't necessarily fit the screen.

There are two ways that I see to resolve this, both seem impossible:

1. Define the size properties wrt the canvas and not the screen.
2. Go to the proper zoom level, and draw all elements even if they aren't in the figure clip region (save to a pdf).

Questions on the subject asked about specific elements such as lines or markers. The suggested solutions were to draw with alternative functions such as patch() and rectangle().

In that case, I'll forsake matlab's clunky drawing mechanism altogether, export the data, and draw in svg. But it would be a shame since matlab has powerful tools such as different marker shapes or a force graph.

Am I missing something fundamental or is this the worst design I've seen lately?

Duplicate:

[www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1569953-plot-elements-of-specific-size](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1569953-plot-elements-of-specific-size)

Comment: What you described is exactly my intention, and indeed it's similar to a rasterized image but I want a vector one. See my comment for a couple of minutes ago in the matlab link. Drawing should be done in a canvas off screen and not on the screen limited by it.

Answer (score 1):

Matt J. observed that, in fact, when saving a pdf, there's no resolution limit regardless of the figure limitation.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1569953-plot-elements-of-specific-size

Then, we can do the following:

- Draw a small proof-of-concept plot with the right proportion between elements (markers, edges, and fonts). Save the data-unit-to-point ratio (`sc0` below). Alternatively, you can use the same constant for all your drawings, considering this matlab's default drawing ratio.
- Draw a plot of any complexity with similar proportions.
- Scale it to have the same ratio as the saved one.
- Save to pdf.

For example:

```
% draw a vertical polyline with n vertices
n = 5; % polyline size
y = 0:n;
plot( zeros( size(y) ), y, '-o', 'LineWidth', 2, 'MarkerSize', 10 );
axis equal;

% scale
sc0 = 51; % ratio calculated by data_units_to_points_ratio() from the initial (designed) fig of a polyline of size 5
sc = data_unit_to_point_ratio() / sc0;
scale_fig_objects( sc );

% save
print( 'plot.pdf' );
```

If you change `n=100`, the figure would be a proportional mess (a thin line, markers not showing), but the pdf would be fine, having the same segment (vertex to edge) proportion.

Functions used:

```
% Based on Matt's suggestion
function conversionFactor = data_unit_to_point_ratio()

set( gcf, 'Units', 'points' );
DU = diff(xlim); % width of figure in data units
hfig = gcf;
P = hfig.Position(3); % width of figure in points
conversionFactor = P / DU; % conversion factor, data units to points
```

and

```
function scale_fig_objects( s )

hs = findobj;

for i = 1:length( hs )
    h = hs(i);
    t = h.Type;
    if strcmpi( t, 'line' ) || strcmpi( t, 'GraphPlot' )
        h.LineWidth = h.LineWidth * s;
        h.MarkerSize = h.MarkerSize * s;
    elseif strcmpi( t, 'scatter' )
        h.SizeData = h.SizeData * s^2; % it's a squared factor!
    elseif strcmpi( t, 'text' )
        h.FontSize = h.FontSize * s;
    end
end
```